Неопределенный класс в аргументах метода у интерфейса
public interface ClassWithList {
    public void clearList();
    public void tryAdd(Class<T> b);
    public void update(Class<T> c);
}

При расширении указываю конкретный класс, и возникает ошибка.
public class Test implements ClassWithList {
    @Override
    public void clearList() {}
    
    @Override
    public void tryAdd(Test b) {
        // Error
    }
    
    @Override
    public void update(Test c) {
        // Error
    }
}

Может ли Java расширять интерфейс подобным образом?
Подскажите, что я делаю не так.
Спасибо!

Сначала надо починить ошибку в ClassWithList. И сразу станет ясно как исправить ошибку в Test.

@talexmovedtoCodidact здесь нет ошибки, интерфейс должен быть универсален для приема объекта любого класса. Я уже получил ответ, продолжайте ставить минусы.

В ответе в первом параграфе указано на ошибку в ClassWithList. Попробуйте читать перед тем как писать.

@talexmovedtoCodidact господи, ну ясен пень что там ОШИБКА, иначе я бы сюда не пришёл. Мне нужно было понять, как интерфейс обобщенным сделать.

А почему вопрос про другой класс? "Потрудитесь изъяснятся яснее".

@talexmovedtoCodidact В заголовке написано класс использующий интерфейс - неопределён.

Фраза "При расширении указываю конкретный класс, и возникает ошибка." означает что до этого ошибки не было. Советую формулировать вопрос так, чтобы его можно было однозначно интерпретировать.

Поскольку в представленном коде возникают ошибки компиляции, связанные с неопределённым типом T в интерфейсе ClassWithList, прежде всего нужно решить эту проблему.

cannot find symbol  
public void tryAdd(Class<T> b);
                         ^
symbol:   class T
location: interface ClassWithList

error: cannot find symbol
public void update(Class<T> c);
                         ^


Для этого существуют два способа:

Объявить интерфейс ClassWithList обобщённым
В таком случае аргументы у методов tryAdd, update будут использовать один и тот же тип.
При этом, в методах tryAdd, update аргумент должен иметь тип T, а не Class<T>, если в классе Test, реализующем данный интерфейс, аргумент в упомянутых методах должен иметь тип Test:

public interface ClassWithList<T> {
    public void clearList();
    public void tryAdd(T b);
    public void update(T c);
}

Тогда при объявлении класса Test следует указать в угловых скобках тип класса-параметра:
public class Test implements ClassWithList<Test> {
    @Override public void clearList() {}
    @Override public void tryAdd(Test b) {}
    @Override public void update(Test c) {}
}

Такая реализация наиболее естественная, в указанные методы можно передавать экземпляры класса Test:
Test t = new Test();
t.tryAdd(t);


1.а) Если аргументы в упомянутых методах по какой-либо причине должны сохранить тип Class<T>, потребуется следует изменить реализацию, чтобы она соответствовала интерфейсу.
public interface ClassWithListA<T> {
    public void clearList();
    public void tryAdd(Class<T> b);
    public void update(Class<T> c);
}

public class TestA implements ClassWithListA<TestA> {
    @Override public void clearList() {}
    @Override public void tryAdd(Class<TestA> b) {}
    @Override public void update(Class<TestA> c) {}
}

При вызове методов в данной реализации можно передавать только тип, известный на момент компиляции, т.е. TestA.class:
ClassWithListA t2 = new TestA();
// ок
t2.update(TestA.class);
// ошибка
t2.update(t2.getClass()); 
// Class cannot be converted to Class
// where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
//   CAP#1 extends TestA from capture of ? extends TestA



Объявить каждый из методов tryAdd, update как обобщённый

public interface ClassWithListB {
    public void clearList();
    public <T> void tryAdd(Class<T> b);
    public <T> void update(Class<T> c);
}

Поскольку в объявлении этого интерфейса не указан параметр типа, он сам по себе не обобщённый, поэтому в реализации также останутся обобщённые методы:
class TestB implements ClassWithListB {
    @Override public void clearList() {}
    @Override public <T> void tryAdd(Class<T> b) {}
    @Override public <T> void update(Class<T> c) {}
}

То есть, в них можно будет передавать объекты любых классов:
ClassWithListB t3 = new TestB();

t3.update(ClassWithListA.class);
t3.tryAdd("abcd".getClass());
t3.update(t2.getClass());
t3.tryAdd(t3.getClass());

Вопрос о необходимости такой реализации остается открытым.

Благодарю за пояснение!!!!!

Вопрос о необходимости такой реализации  : я пишу свою программу, я использую такой подход для классов которые хранят внутри себя коллекции. Я бы хотел чтобы каждый класс имеющий такую коллекцию гарантировал проверку условия.

К сожалению не помогло, ну как, оно работает да. Но к методам переданного объекта класса, доступа нет, Буду ставить Object и делать cast.
Спасибо за ваше время

@PerfectVoyage, можете уточнить, что значит к методам переданного объекта класса, доступа нет?

Перечитал ваш ответ внимательнее, первый способ подходит!!!!!!!!!
Спасибо большое!!!!!!!
